# Why must the master key be stronger than the session key?

Tags: key-management, key-generation, key-exchange

If I am going to use a master key to generate a session key, the master key must be "stronger" than the session key.

For instance, I should not be distributing a 128-bit AES keys with a 56-bit DES key.

Why?

Comment: It seems you completely changed this question into a new one. Please dont do that. Instead ask a new question.

Comment: @Anders Sorry about this,i am still quite new to the forum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I should not be distributing a 128-bit AES keys with a 56-bit DES key.
>   Why?

If you think about this, it is trivially obvious: anyone can obtain the 128 bit key by brute forcing the 56 bit key that you distribute it under. The performance of your security is defined by the weakest point in the system.